# How to parse Dictionary in Swift coming as JSON?

Tags: json, parsing, dictionary, swift

I have tried almost every way and combination to resolve the issue with parsing Dictionary coming from server. I know I would be missing something but the error messages are not very helpful as they were in Objective C.

Here is the response from server. Its an array of Dictionary:

```
{
        commentCount = 0;
        "country_id" = 225;
        "country_name" = "Cdscd";
        dislikeCount = 0;
        disliked = 0;
        firstname = cddd;
        imageHeight = 0;
        imagePath = "";
        imageWidth = 0;
        lastname = dccd;
        likeCount = 0;
        liked = 0;
        postid = 127;
        posttime = "2014-10-28 17:50:00";
        statusUpdate = "gygbibcsa";
        "upload_type" = text;
        userId = 78;
        userimage = "https://harsh.com/nrnimages/1410142960.png";
        videoHeight = "";
        videoPath = "";
        videoThumbnail = "";
        videoWidth = "";
    },
        {
        commentCount = 0;
        "country_id" = 225;
        "country_name" = "United States";
        dislikeCount = 0;
        disliked = 0;
        firstname = ssssss;
        imageHeight = 0;
        imagePath = "";
        imageWidth = 0;
        lastname = Shssssh;
        likeCount = 0;
        liked = 0;
        postid = 122;
        posttime = "2014-10-27 06:31:38";
        statusUpdate = Hello;
        "upload_type" = text;
        userId = 13;
        userimage = "https://harsh.com/nrnimages/1409976093.png";
        videoHeight = "";
        videoPath = "";
        videoThumbnail = "";
        videoWidth = "";
    }
```

Now I have assigned this array in my own Array like follows:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://www.harsh.com/temp/Api/v1/homepage", parameters:objHomeDataDictionary, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON
{
    (request, response, JSON, error) in

    print("Error homepage:",error)

    if var objArray = JSON as? NSArray
    {
        self.homePageDataArray = objArray
    }
}
```

Now at each index of Array there is a dictionary and I have to get that and show the data from each dictionary in the Table View but I am not getting how to do this.

Comment: So it isn't the parsing you are having difficulty with, it's getting the data out if the array? Have you tried using subscripts? What error messages are you getting.

Comment: @Abizern Yes, I have tried almost every way but every time it is showing errors with Type Conversion.

Comment: It helps if you actually show what the errors are. Swift is strongly typed and those messages are useful for debugging.

Comment: Is your server response is correct ? If i consider your given response as a webserver response then it is wrong. It shoud similer like :  {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  }